# Manual SQL install error

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am receiving the following error when trying to manually install my SQL:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host' at line 1
```

The following are the first few lines of my SQL code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2014 at 08:53 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.24
-- PHP Version: 5.3.13

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Not the right place to ask this question. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Replace your double dashes (--) with a pound sign (#) and give it another shot. MySQL can be picky about -- in scripts ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-comments.html)